# is a "dynamic" exe possible?

Tags: c#, ruby, windows, winforms

I was wondering if, using reflection, I could make changes to the codefile / portable executable at runtime, and have them saved. So technically the executable is saving changes to itself. I have and am doing this by having two executable, one just simply reads the bytes of another, edits, rearranges them and overwrites. I was just wondering if there is a clever reflection option, using .Net? If not, do any other languages that run on windows have this feature? I've heard a lot of good things about Ruby. If youre interested, the goal is to have have my own custom database class compiled into my exe, as my programs database.

Comment: What original task are you trying to solve. There is a chance you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @sebsilver why are you building such class into the EXE instead of creating a satellite assembly?????? How easy could turn your goal if you do this way..

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, yes I know it would be easier to do it that way, I was wondering if I could do it this way.

Comment: @zerkms, I am trying to embed my db into my assemble as a class, but I am interested in the question for the sake of it as well.

Comment: @Seb Silver: what does "embed my db into my assemble as a class" mean?

Comment: You cannot write to the exe file of a running process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktq-22iq-Po) of a Ruby script in action which rewrites itself. By [Yusuke Endoh](http://mamememo.blogspot.nl/2010/09/qlobe.html); there is [more](http://mamememo.blogspot.nl/2010/12/merry-quine-mas-2010.html).

Comment: And doing that is a nightmare in waiting; Self-modifying code in assembly language used to be done when we were working with 16K RAM, but these days?

Comment: @theTinMan Have you seen them? They are both not serious code - the last one builds it's own code looking like four snowmen in moving ascii-art snow, while playing Jingle Bells.

Comment: I haven't seen those. In general, self-modifying code is very undesirable.